# Why does filter view by custom formula NOT work for this formula that detects first unique entry in column?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, spreadsheet

When trying to answer [Cowboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7615968)'s [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134654/remove-rows-based-on-duplicates-in-a-single-column-in-google-sheets), I came across the following curious/frustrating situation.

Say in column A, we have something like `{"";"a";"b";"a";"c";"b"}`.

If in column B, we populate the cells with the formula

```
=iserror(match(A2,A$1:A1,0))
```

starting with the second row, the output will be `{"";TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE}` because the formula checks if the entry has not occurred above it.

But if we use this formula in the Filter by condition with custom formula -- with the correct index offset, it doesn't work. Why?

---

By correct index offset, I mean that

> Filter by condition with custom formula iterates the formula with position centered on the cell **below** the cell with the filter view setting.

Why is it not documented? That could be a good question for Google Support (should it exist).

Comment: Hi @Argyll, sample file would help us.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov: In a new sheet, if you enter `{"";"a";"b";"a";"c";"b"}` in `A1` and the formula in column B starting with `B2` as described in the question, you will see the result as described in the question. I am not sure if you will see the same filter view result. But that's the issue raised in the question. I see the problem repeated on my end. I would like to know how it works for others. Could you kindly give it a try on your end please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(ROW(A:A),"<="&ROW(A2),A:A,A2))=1`

And the range:

```
2 a
3 b
4 a
5 c
6 b
```

will be filtered into first instances of each value:

```
2 a
3 b
5 c
```

---

Your formula `=iserror(match(A2,A$1:A1,0))` does not work because you are trying to mimic the behavior of a formula:

- when it is dragged down, the range will slip down: `A$1:A1 → A$1:A2 → A$1:A3...`
- when the formula is applied to the filter, the range will remain the same: `A$1:A1 → A$1:A1 → A$1:A1...`